# How to getting items count in SPListitem in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

My friend is having a problem in SharePoint that he is accessing the SharePoint sqlserver database.

The code is :

```
SPListItemCollection collListItems = oList.Items;
foreach (SPListItem item in collListItems)
    {
        Response.WriteLine(item[0]);
        Response.WriteLine(item[1]);
        Response.WriteLine(item[2]);
        Response.WriteLine(item[3]);
    }
```

In the `foreach` loop, the item variable does not have the `Length` nor the `Count` property and he wants to write generalized code, but is unable to loop on item.
Can anybody please tell that how can we iterate the item inside the `foreach` loop?
Currently it is looking like item(0) item(1) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do that since there are a lot of default fields but here is how you to do it:

```
foreach (SPField field in oList.Fields)
{
    Response.WriteLine(item[field.Id])
}
```